# All regex matches inside of one value

Tags: c#, regex

I input a string into this function such as `var o="ok"`. This works but when I try two or more the value is stuff like `b"var o="ok`.

I have already tried every match method I know but it doesn't work, I can't find anything wrong wrong with the pattern.

```cs
public List<Varible> GetVars(string code)
{
    List<Varible> vars = new List<Varible>();
    Regex dagu = new Regex("var\\s+\\w+=(\\s+|)\"(.+|)\"");
    Match reg = dagu.Match(code);
    while (reg.Success) {

        Match fef = reg;
        Varible v = new Varible();
        v.vartype = vartype.o_string;
        v.name = fef.Value.Substring(fef.Value.IndexOf("r") + 1, fef.Value.IndexOf("=") - fef.Value.IndexOf("r") - 1);
        int b = fef.Value.LastIndexOf("\"");
        int f = fef.Value.IndexOf("\"");
        v.value = fef.Value.Substring(f + 1, b - f - 1);
        vars.Add(v);
        reg = reg.NextMatch();

}
    return vars;
}
```

There are no errors reported.

Comment: Please provide few examples of the full input strings and the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your pattern:

```
"var\\s+\\w+=(\\s+|)\"(.+|)\""
```

A): The two capturing groups are not exactly wrong, but they're oddly written. `(\\s+|)` captures "one or more spaces, OR nothing at all", which can be expressed as "zero or more spaces". In regex, the "zero or more" quantifier is the star, so you can replace this group with `(\\s*)`. Same for `(.+|)` which becomes `(.*)`.
Then there's the issue with trying to match this pattern multiple times: the `.+`/`.*`pattern can, and will match quotes. To avoid this you can replace the dot by a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that will match anything except for quotes: `[^\"]`.
So now your pattern should look like this:

```
"var\\s+\\w+=(\\s*)\"([^\"]*)\""
```

B): Then... You don't use any of this. You seem to only use the match as a whole and redo the pattern by hand to get the part you need. I understand you added the parentheses in your pattern to be able to use the | operator, but they also have the nifty effect of creating [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). A capturing group, for short, is what you're asking your regex engine to specifically look for and point out for you when matching. You can access these groups with the `Match.Groups` property. In your case, because there are two pairs of parentheses in your pattern, you'll create two groups, the first one contains the spacing between the equal sign and the first quote of your input. You don't seem to need it, so let's remove it, and instead capture the name of your 'var':

```
"var\\s+(\\w+)=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\""
```

You can now access the var's name with `reg.Groups[1].Value` and its value with `Groups[2]`, and before you ask, `reg.Groups[0].Value` does exist but it always stores the entire match, so for your purposes it's the same as `reg.Value`.

Now to overhaul all this code:

```
public List<Varible> GetVars(string code)
{
    List<Varible> vars = new List<Varible>();
    Regex dagu = new Regex("var\\s+(\\w+)=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"");
    Match reg = dagu.Match(code);
    while (reg.Success) 
    {
        Varible v = new Varible();
        v.vartype = vartype.o_string;
        v.name = reg.Groups[1].Value;
        v.value = reg.Groups[2].Value;
        vars.Add(v);
        reg = reg.NextMatch();
    }
    return vars;
}
```

and you should be good.

Comment: this is correct, thank you for helping me understand regex more :)